# React.JS - Disable Right Click in the full App But Enable it only in some pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to disable right-click for my full react app, but want to enable the right-click in some pages.

```js
function handelRightClick(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}

document.addEventListener('contextmenu', handelRightClick);
```

But I want to `removeEventListener` only if the user opens a particular page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addEventListener` in App component and `removeEventListener` when we don't want it, to do so we want the same reference of the `handelRightClick` function. export that `handelRightClick` function and import it wherever we want.

> App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { handelRightClick } from ./AppUtility;

export default function App() {
  document.addEventListener('contextmenu', handelRightClick);
  return <h1>App Component</h1>
}
```

> AppUtility.js

```js
export function handelRightClick(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

> User.js

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { handelRightClick } from ./AppUtility;

export default function User() {
  document.removeEventListener('contextmenu', handelRightClick);


  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      document.addEventListener('contextmenu', handelRightClick);      
    };
  },[]);
  return <h1>User Component</h1>
}
```

Comment: adding event listeners to document is now deprecated, you must add them to individual dom elements.

Comment: Thanks for the update @sed, can you provide the proper way in the answer section